# Retrieving Assembly without DLL

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my code to retrieve a class from a different solution (both solutions are in the same folder) using an XML file:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("settings.xml");
var query = xml.Elements();
     foreach (var XMLProtocol in query)
     {
         string NameSpace = XMLProtocol.Element("NameSpace").Value;
         string ClassName = XMLProtocol.Element("ClassName").Value;
         string FrequencyType = XMLProtocol.Element("FrequencyType").Value;
         string FrequencyValue = XMLProtocol.Element("FrequencyValue").Value;
         string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
         System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path + "../../" + NameSpace + "\\bin\\Debug\\" + NameSpace + ".dll");
         System.Type type = assembly.GetType(NameSpace + '.' + ClassName);
         Protocol protocol = new Protocol((IProtocol)Activator.CreateInstance(type), Convert.ToInt64(int.Parse(FrequencyValue) * GetFrequencyTypeMultiplier(FrequencyType)));
         this.Add(protocol);
     }
Execute();
```

This is the XML:

```xml
<Protocols>
  <Protocol>
    <NameSpace>ClassTest</NameSpace>
    <ClassName>Class1</ClassName>
    <FrequencyType>Minute</FrequencyType>
    <FrequencyValue>20</FrequencyValue>
  </Protocol>
</Protocols>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the assembly without having to "hardcode" the path to the DLL? What is the best practice for that scenario?

Comment: A simple thing: Proper indentation goes a long way, specifically there's no reason for the for-each-loop being indented an extra-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this feels very "examplish", here are my thoughts:

Personally, I would rethink how you handle paths currently. As it stands, the directory structure **must** be very specific: you are provided with some "root" folder, and in that folder you have subfolders, each named after the `namespace` of the library within it, then a `bin` folder, then a `Debug` folder, so an example would be:

> ```
> C:\Projects\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll
> C:\Projects\Project2\bin\Debug\Project2.dll
> C:\Projects\ClassTest\bin\Debug\ClassTest.dll
> et. al.
> ```

If you just wanted to drop a bunch of files in one folder, it's currently not possible.

Why don't you, instead, add the path as a line in the XML file?

```
<Protocols>
  <Protocol>
    <NameSpace>ClassTest</NameSpace>
    <ClassName>Class1</ClassName>
    <FrequencyType>Minute</FrequencyType>
    <FrequencyValue>20</FrequencyValue>
    <FolderPath>../../ClassTest/bin/Debug/</FolderPath>
  </Protocol>
</Protocols>
```

The nicety of this is that you can now put your DLL's *anywhere*. You can use relative, absolute and virtual paths, and you can make them much more dynamic.

```
C:\Projects\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll
C:\Projects\Project2\bin\Release\Project2.dll
C:\Dean Martin\ClassTest.dll
et. al.
```

This also means, that if you wish to use the release version of `Project1`, but the debug version of `Project2`, you can! Just include the appropriate path name!

This is generally the best-practice for this situation, as the "location" of a DLL file is a configuration aspect, rather than a programme aspect. Only in certain situations (with things like dynamic plugins) would you use a hardcoded (absolute, virtual, or relative: any of the three) path to get to the DLL's. And that would typically be something like `Plugins\`.

---

On a separate topic: I would recommend you use the `@` prefix for your path strings, to be able to omit escapes:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path + "../../" + NameSpace + @"\bin\Debug\" + NameSpace + ".dll");
```

This tends to make it more readable. Of course, if you move the file paths to the XML, it won't be a problem. :)

Comment: Before I had the path to the DLL inside the xml file, but my boss said it's not required, that I could do it just with the class name and namespace. So I made that change because I couln't figure out how to make the assembly works without the DLL. I'll probably have to change the string when I won't be in Debug though. The dynamic plugins part you mentioned seems to be my case, I'll see if I can find more about it.

Comment: @loli I would consider reading [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx) on the recommended way to build a Plug-In Framework.

Comment: I got it to work without DLL by reading the MSDN article, thanks ! No more path needed.

Comment: @loli Ah, excellent!